# Kruskal-Wallis, ANOVA, or other tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I am really struggling to find out a proper statistical test to use for my dataset. Below is my dataset description:

- Latency of response (in ms) collected from 24 animals
- Data from each animal has been collected repeatedly: several days, but also several times within a day.
- Depending on the animal, it has ~830 data points or as little as ~175 data points.
- Animals can be divided into two conditions (experimental (n = 12) and control (n = 12)) and I would like to test if there are effects between the experimental and control groups

Some tests that I were thinking

- Kruskal wallis: I would simply group the data points from 12 animals in each experimental conditions into one and then do a KW test between the groups.
- Permutation test: similar as above
- Repeated measures ANOVA: because I have 12 animals in each group, I could consider each animal as a repeated measure?

I have tested for normality of each animal (830 data points for examples) but they seem to be non-normal. I read that normality violation is not a huge deal for ANOVA, but I also seem to have an issue with unequal variances. When I test the variance between 1 animal vs. the other, there seems to be a significant difference with the two-sample F test.

What would be the advisable way to handle this data? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a multilevel model with latency as the dependent variable, group as the fixed effect, and animal as a random effect. You might (or might not) want other effects added -- time, in particular, might be worth adding.